# Page numbers instead of 4 images for pagination in tablesorterpager plugin -- Possible?

Tags: javascript, tablesorter, pager

I am using Tablesorter plugin along with the tablesorterpager plugin.
I was wondering by default it shows 4 images for pagination purpose, Move first, move previous, move next and move last respectively.
Is there a way to show page numbers instead of images.
I have tried but was not able to figure out where to change the code in the plugin js file.

Thanks

Sweety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Not the most elegant solution, but I modified the pager to include some page numbers by modifying the `updatePageDisplay` method. Hopefully you'll be able to take it from here.

Checkout the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NiceGuy4263/TFL5p/

**ORIGINAL**

Not sure I understand, you simply want to remove the images? The page numbers seem to show up by default.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

To remove those buttons:

```
$(function(){ $('img.next, img.prev, img.last, img.first').remove(); });
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
I meant , that instead of showing images, how to show Page numbers as links to navigate to different pages.